# My Class Based View(Django) code cant recognize id from SQL database

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I tried to make a training project with forms. I wanted to create a code for upgrading feedbacks in the form by Class Based Views.
views.py

```
class UpdateFeedbackView(View):
    def get(self, request, id_feedback):
        feed = get_object_or_404(Feedback, id=id_feedback)
        form = FeedbackForm(instance=feed)
        return render(request, 'form_project/feedback.html', context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request, id_feedback):
        feed = get_object_or_404(Feedback, id=id_feedback)
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST, instance=feed)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/{id_feedback}')
        else:
            form = FeedbackForm(instance=feed)
        return render(request, 'form_project/feedback.html', context={'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:id_feedback>', views.UpdateFeedbackView.as_view())
```

html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'feedback/field.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Оставьте отзыв</h2>
    <form  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
         <div class="form-style">
             {{ field.errors }}
             {{ field.label_tag }}
             {{ field }}

         </div>
        {% endfor %}




        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i try to type an feedback's id, i get this error
`TemplateDoesNotExist at /1`

The code thinks that id does not exist. However i tried to write the same upgrade code by simple function and it worked well.
By debugger, i realised that problem is in GET method but can't understand why.

What did i wrong or miss?

filetree: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh1lc.png)

Comment: Share the filetree of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your template `form_project/feedback.html` likely is not put in the right directory. This should be moved to `app_name/templates/form_project/feedback.html`.

Your view however implements a lot of boilerplate code, and is equivalent to an [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class UpdateFeedbackView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'form_project/feedback.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('update_feed', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

with as url:

```
path('<int:pk>', views.UpdateFeedbackView.as_view(), name='update_feed'),
```

Comment: Thanks, i've just found out that i wrote a wrong template directory(html folder) in return